# Javascript parallax is laggy on mac

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, macos, parallax

I made a parallax page where the background image is changed with JS

```
translateY(- ... px)'
```

same as seen on [firewatch website](https://www.firewatchgame.com/).

On Windows, it works fine, smoothly. However, on macOS it works smoothly only in Safari. All other browsers are laggy, choppy and I wasn't able to find an answer. I tried CSS transition but that did not help.
Why is firewatch parallax lagging?
I was coding according to [this](https://www.stephanieogaygarcia.com/blog/creating-a-parallax-effect) guide

Comment: What browsers did you tested on on Windows? Are you using the same machine or similar hardware for testing? Also please make sure to share a minimal example of your code demonstrating this problem.

Comment: @Mathyn I tryied firefox for developers, chrome on windows. Windows has high end performance = i7 and mac is late 2015 = i5.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `will-change: transform; transform: translate3d(0, -...px, 0)` to your css, and implement `requestAnimationFrame` to your js. [More info here](https://www.sitepoint.com/7-performance-tips-jank-free-javascript-animations/).

It's not an iOS releated advice, but can improve animations performance and smoothness, and maybe that improvement's enough to make your animation smooth. Sometimes iOS doesn't react to animated transforms too well.

Comment: Thanks for tip. It seems to be smoother, however the jumps are still visible. My code is same as https://www.stephanieogaygarcia.com/blog/creating-a-parallax-effect
this codepen is basically my code https://codepen.io/stephanieogaygarcia/pen/zLvPoB

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the use of GPU by the browser, replace `translateY(...)` for `transform: translate3d(0, ..., 0)`. This will force the browser to use the GPU for rendering and it should work smoother.

Comment: Thanks for tip, however it is doing the same thing. My code is same as this
https://www.stephanieogaygarcia.com/blog/creating-a-parallax-effect
this codepen is basically my code https://codepen.io/stephanieogaygarcia/pen/zLvPoB